# using jetty to test a method that performs http post

Tags: java, junit, jetty

I am writing a junit test for a program that performs HTTP post, I am trying to use jetty to handle the request, but I can't find good examples or explanation on how to use it for that purpose, does anyone have a good example on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this could help anyone, but this is the solution I came up with for my problem, so I thought I share it with you... 
my problem was that in a specific part of the program that I am trying to test with junit, it makes a POST request, and I wanted to validate that it is making the request properly.. of course I could have used mockito to mock the static method that is making the request, but I just thought that using a real server like jetty would be better for testing the request being sent by my program, and this way, all my program would be fully tested, without skipping any part of it... so here is the jetty code I wrote...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

public class JettyHttpServer extends AbstractHandler
{
    private static Server server = null;

    public Server getServer()
    {
        return server;
    }

    public static void startServer(int webServerPort) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Initializing server");
        server = new Server(webServerPort);
        server.setHandler(new JettyHttpServer());
        server.start();
    }

    public static void stopServer() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            server.stop();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("Could not stop server", ex);
        }
    }

    public void handle(String pathInContext, Request request, HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("inside Jetty Server...");
boolean requestWrongFlag = true

        if (httpRequest.getMethod().equals("POST"))
        {
            BufferedReader reader = httpRequest.getReader();
            String line;
            do {
            line = reader.readLine();
//do the validation here on the request received and in case it is not correct raise the requestWrongFlag
            System.out.println(line);
            }while (line!=null);


            httpResponse.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
           if(!requestWrongFlag)
               httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
           else
                       httpResponse.setStatus(httpServletResponse.sc_BAD_REQUEST)
            httpResponse.getWriter().println("OK");
            request.setHandled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

then I called that jetty server in my TestCase just before I call the program under test...

if anyone has better suggestions... please share with me...

Answer (score 0):

a Junit is a unit test, not an integration test. The integration test means that you need have the server up and running to test that feature.

Here you can see an example of a Integration test:

```
     @Test
         public void test() {
                 HttpClient loggedClient = new HttpClient();
                 PostMethod loginPostMethod = new PostMethod(loginURL);
                 loginPostMethod.addParameter("j_username", login);
                 loginPostMethod.addParameter("j_password", password);
                 loginPostMethod.addParameter("remember", "1");
                 loginPostMethod.addParameter("clientType", clientType);
                 loginPostMethod.addParameter("clientVersion", clientVersion);
                  httpClient.executeMethod(postMethod);


                 String USERS_URL = HTTP_SERVER_DOMAIN + "/service";
                 PutMethod put = new PutMethod(USERS_URL);
                 put.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                 put.setRequestBody("your_body");

                 try {
                     loggedClient.executeMethod(put);
                 } catch (HttpException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }

                 assertEquals(HttpStatus.SC_OK, put.getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: thank you paul for your answer, I really appreciate it. But this isn'tmy case. I have a program that makes a webservice call, gets some data and then either store it in a database or POST it to an HTTP server. I have managed to create a mock webservice using axis2 code generator and deployed it in a .war file and used it in jetty, also managed to test the JDBC part of the program using hsql and dbunit... but I can't really figure out a way to test the part of the program where it send POST request to the HTTP server... that's why I was asking if I could use jetty for that... what do you think?

Comment: If the webService is a thirdparty service and shall work always as you expect it, definitely you need to use a mock(I suggest you mockito). You have to realize that what you want to test, is how you serialize and deserialize the information that you send and receive from that WS. In any case the example that I paste to you is perfectly valid to make a request to whatever web service.

Comment: well, you've got a point there... maybe I'll try mockito... thnx for your help :)